# Firebase function to check App Distribution is deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to write a Firebase cloud function that get's triggered when you deploy an apk to App Distribution.
Is there any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Right now this isn't possible, but the team is considering it going forward. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help.